# How to wait for the angular universal to fully charge?

Tags: angular-universal

My application works perfectly without angular universal . I display an image before the complete loading of my application(https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-style-angular-application-loading-with-angular-cli-like-a-boss-cdd4f5358554) but it does not work in anular Universal. It displays nothing. When rendering angular universal the breakpoint hits come too late and i want to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

Angular Universal's entire point is that it will render on the server and not in the browser. So the article you linked in terms of having a loading image while Angular bootstraps won't happen with Universal as it's already "bootstrapped" on the server before it's given to you in the browser.

Another way to think about it is that you can use a loading gif **OR** use Angular Universal to achieve a similar result of not giving a user a blank screen.

In terms of the second part of your question with breakpoints not being hit. Again this is a quirk with Angular Universal in that because the first page request is rendered on the server, if you are attempting to debug something in the browser it's not going to work as you might first think because the rendering has already happened server side. To debug Angular Universal you need to debug both in browser, and using something like VS Code to debug as a regular NodeJS app. If that sounds like a headache it's because it is. Unless you have a really good reason to use Universal, I wouldn't recommend using it just because you can.

More info :

- https://angular.io/guide/universal
- https://tutorialsforangular.com/2020/04/04/3-things-they-dont-tell-you-about-angular-universal/

Comment: Thank you @MindingData. Unfortunately i need an angular unversal for SEO. How to wait for the angular universal to fully charge? Can you give an example? Thank you